# I want to create ECS architecture using terraform script.My instance is not connect with ECS

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

Here i attached the code for terraform script. I need a One ECS cluster, service and task with auto scalling with EC2 instance.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-south-1"
}
resource "aws_key_pair" "my_key_pair" {
  key_name   = "any"
  public_key = file("~/.ssh/any.pub")
}
resource "aws_security_group" "my_security_group" {
  name        = "ecs-demo-security-group"
  description = "Allow SSH and HTTP traffic"
  vpc_id      = "vpc-xxxx" # Replace with your VPC ID
  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 3000
    to_port     = 3000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name = "ecs-demo"
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "my_execution_role" {
  name = "ecs-demo-execution-role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole",
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_execution_role_attachment" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.my_execution_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_instance_role" {
  name = "ecs-instance-role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole",
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_instance_role_attachment" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_instance_role.name
}
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ecs_instance_profile" {
  name = "ecs-instance-profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.ecs_instance_role.name
}
resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "my_capacity_provider" {
  name = "my-ecs-demo-capacity-provider"
  
  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn = aws_autoscaling_group.my_autoscaling_group.arn
    managed_scaling {
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 100
    }
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "ecs-demo"
  }
}
resource "aws_launch_template" "my_launch_template" {
  name = "ecs-demo-launch-template"
  #image_id      = "ami-0449c34f967dbf18a"
  image_id = "ami-076bbae7511f2cc74"
  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"
    ebs {
      volume_size = 30
      volume_type = "gp2"
    }
  }
  key_name = aws_key_pair.my_key_pair.key_name
  instance_type = "t2.micro" # Specify your preferred instance type for on-demand instances
  iam_instance_profile {
    name = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs_instance_profile.name
  }
  network_interfaces {
    security_groups=[aws_security_group.my_security_group.id]  
  }
  user_data = base64encode(<<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              echo ECS_CLUSTER=${aws_ecs_cluster.my_cluster.name} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
              echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
              EOF
  )

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"

    tags = {
      Name = "ecs-demo"
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "my_autoscaling_group" {
  desired_capacity     = 1
  max_size             = 2
  min_size             = 1

  
  mixed_instances_policy {
    launch_template {
      launch_template_specification {
        launch_template_id = aws_launch_template.my_launch_template.id
        version            = "$Latest"
      }
    }

    instances_distribution {
      spot_allocation_strategy                  = "lowest-price"
      on_demand_allocation_strategy             = "prioritized"
      on_demand_base_capacity                   = 0
      on_demand_percentage_above_base_capacity = 0
    }
  }

  vpc_zone_identifier  = ["subnet-xxxx"] # Replace with your subnet IDs

  tag {
    key                 = "AmazonECSManaged"
    value               = true
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "my_task" {
  family                   = "ecs-demo-task"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["EC2"]
  cpu                      = "256"
  memory                   = "512"

  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.my_execution_role.arn
  
  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "name": "ecs-demo",
      "image": "ecr_image_arn",
      "cpu": 256,
      "memory": 512,
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  DEFINITION
}
resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_ecs_service" {
  name            = "ecs-demo-service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.my_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.my_task.arn
  desired_count   = 1
  launch_type     = "EC2"
  
  network_configuration {
    subnets         = ["subnet-xxxx"] # Replace with your subnet IDs
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_security_group.id]
  }

}
```

It's my terafform script.I found issue with capacity provider. I am creating capacity provider but It was not associate with ECS cluster.

Please share your idea about that.
Please correct the script where i am make wrong.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you check if `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` contains correct cluster name?

Comment: Yes there are custer name is exists.

Comment: I got solution. I am not connecting load balancer with ECS Service.
```load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.my_target_group.arn
    container_name   = "ecs-demo"
    container_port   = 3000
  }``` .By adding this thing I will archive my goal.